# Class and Inner class access modifier

Tags: java

It may be a repeated question. 
But i need a clear answer for this answer.
I am so confused.

For EG:
I have class to display time.

```
import java.util.Date;

**public** class DateDisplay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println(today);
    }
}
```

None of the class in the same package is going to extend this class. 
Why can not i declare a class at private?

Why JAVA is not allowing me to declare a class as private? What is the reason behind this?

My second question is where should i use inner class?
What is purpose of inner class?

Comment: What would you do with a private (top-level) class? it would not be accessible from anywhere.

Comment: As **one** question per question.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: @downvoter: explain please. not for the question atleast reason for vote.

Comment: I want to know the reason for this.
Just asking why compiler is not allowing us to declare a class as private.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use it anywhere. Having a private top level class makes no sense.

Comment: You can't have a private top-level class because A) [That's how the language is designed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1), and B) It makes no sense, as it would only be accessible via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question: If you want to get this done define a public/protected class with in it a private class. As a result the private class is only accessible within its class.

```
Example:
public class x
{
  private class y
  {
  }
}
```

Here class y is only accessible in class x 
I guess this also answers your second question,
see for more info 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Access modifiers on a class do not only specify where you can extend the class; they also specify where the class can be used.

`private` means: accessible only inside the class itself. It would not make sense for a top-level class to be `private`, because that would mean you could not use the class at all - any other classes would't be able to use it.

If you want to make a class inaccessible to classes outside the package, then use the default access level (don't specify an access modifier at all):

```
// Only accessible within the same package
class DateDisplay {
    // ...
}
```

Note however, that a class with a `main` method should be `public`.